# 2D Barcode Scanner, with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I'm looking to find a Bluetooth 2D Barcode scanner. I work at a local schoolboard and we receive shipments of Chromebooks for student use, so we have to tag and inventory each unit by inventory number and serial number.

The boxes have a QR code (which contains the serial number) and we place a standard UPC barcode on them. I've been using an Android phone to scan these, but it takes more time than a scanner usually does (focusing camera, etc).

I just have four requirements:

1. Reads QR and standard barcodes (UPC). Datamatrix codes would be nice too, but necessary.
2. Uses bluetooth, not a 2.4Ghz receiver.
3. Under $250
4. Easy to read instructions, in English.

I had found [this scanner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GRI34YM), but when we went to order it, it became unavailable. So, now I'm on the hunt for a new one and thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it have to be bluetooth?

Comment: @Andy Mainly because I can't do the scanning near a computer, for space reasons, and I didn't want a proprietary receiver dongle that we could easily lose. Bluetooth is cross-platform and if we do our scanning off-site, we can use our phones to hold and upload the scanned data.

Comment: @reeeky2001 - The wireless ones from Symbol don't have a dongle. they have a charging cradle that connects via USB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having done many ERP integrations in warehouses and retail, there was pretty much one wireless barcode scanner that stood out and that was [Symbol](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/scanners.html) (now Zebra).

[image]

They do make a [Bluetooth scanner - DS6878SR](https://goo.gl/ZVm8tB) and given your (increased) budget this should work nicely.

Personally, I wouldn't go for the smaller name scanners.  Symbol is an industry standard and their reliability is unmatched.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've suggested the [DS6878-SR](https://www.amazon.com/Zebra-Motorola-Symbol-DS6878-SR-Bluetooth/dp/B00NN63AD2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476465913&sr=8-1&keywords=zebra+2d+bluetooth) as the LS4278 doesn't do 2D.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I got the boss to increase the budget on it. But big time thanks for reminding me of Zebra. We used Moto scanners all the time when I worked retail.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again. I received my DS6878 yesterday and got it working as I needed it to.